# Error while accessing Publish in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, .net

I got this error while accessing `Publish` in Visual Studio 2017 ASP NET project.

**Error**

> Publish has encountered an error. Method 'GetDefauttFactoryPriority in
>   type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Azure.DockerPublish.DockerPubl
>   ishProfileVisualFactory from assembly
>   'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Azure.DockerPublish, Version=15.0.0.0,
>   Culture= neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' does not have an
>   implementation.  A diagnostic log has been written to the following
>   location: 'CAUsers \Administrator.QUCE-PCO5\AppData \ Local \Temp Vmp4
>   A47.tmp'

Please check below image for error details.

[image]

**This is the info on tmp4a47**

> System.TypeLoadException: Method 'GetDefaultFactoryPriority' in type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Azure.DockerPublish.DockerPublishProfileVisualFactory' from assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Azure.DockerPublish, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' does not have an implementation.
>     at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Azure.DockerPublish.DockerPublishProfileVisualFactoryProvider.CreateFactory(IPublishServiceProvider provider)
>     at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ApplicationCapabilities.Publish.ViewModel.ProfileSelectorViewModel.LoadFactories(IPublishServiceProvider serviceProvider, IVsHierarchy hierarchy)
>     at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ApplicationCapabilities.Publish.ViewModel.ProfileSelectorViewModel..ctor(Dispatcher dispatcher, IAsyncServiceProvider vsServiceProvider, IPublishServiceProvider serviceProvider, IVsHierarchy hierarchy)
>     at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ApplicationCapabilities.Publish.Provider.DefaultPublishTabProvider.CreateViewAsync(IVsHierarchy project, IAsyncServiceProvider serviceProvider, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>     at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ApplicationCapabilities.Publish.Provider.ManagedPublishProvider.d__3.MoveNext()

Comment: Images are not good to analyze the problem, it would be better if you post your error message along

Comment: @PrashantPimpale If you can help now.

Comment: thank you for editing my post @GaurangDave

Comment: @Rinard Welcome to StackoverFlow. Please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and learn about [how to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @GaurangDave noted, I hope someone can help me on my problem anyway thank you again

Comment: @Rinard are you publishing on Azure Server? Or IIS Or Local Directory

Comment: @PrashantPimpale IIS only

Comment: After hit publish button there is a option `configure`, click on configure link and check the publish method option

Comment: when I click the publish button the error show then no more option shown

Comment: Can you give us some info from the file at "CAUsers \Administrator.QUCE-PCO5\AppData \ Local \Temp Vmp4 A47.tmp"? Also this might help: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/210559/vs2017-156-publish-web-application-fails.html

Comment: @MindSwipe i already include the info from tmp4a47 as per you ask

Comment: There have been some issues with publishing, did you check for updates for your visual studio? The issue you have might have been fixed already.

Comment: I have the same issue having upgraded to `Visual Studio 2017 Community 15.9.3`. So the issue doesn't appear fixed in the latest version. Any guidance gladly received - I have Googled for some time and no obvious answers...

Answer (score 0):

Yep. Bug in Visual Studio after the latest update...

Now I publish through the command line (with admin rights):

```
> cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin
> msbuild C:\Icons8\Icons8.Search\Icons8.Search.csproj /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile=FolderProfile
```